# Difference between findBy and findOneBy in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

All i know so far is that FindBy can return multiple results while FindOneBy will return a single result or null when we use it the following way.

```
List<Department> findByDepartmentName(String name);
Department findOneByDepartmentId(Long Id);
```

now, my question is, can i use findBy this way?

```
Department  findByDepartmentId(Long Id);
```

If yes,

- Lets assume there are multiple records for given Id.
- On what basis does *findBydepartmentId*  return a single record?

Finally, When or Why should i not use  findBy in place of findOneBy?

Comment: I have the same question, have you gotten to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Can I use `findBy` this way? Department  `findByDepartmentId(Long Id)`;

Yes, this syntax is technically correct from Spring JPA point of view. Although Spring JPA infers what you're trying to achieve with your query looking at the **return type** as well.

Basically these are the cases for return types:

- with your query you want to return a single value - you can specify `basic type`, `Entity T`, [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), [`CompletableFuture<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) etc.
- with your query you want to return a collection of T - you can specify [`List<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Stream<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), [`Page<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html), [`Slice<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) etc.

That being said, your query definition:

```
Department findByDepartmentId(Long Id);
```

means that you expect a single result (because you've specified `Entity T` as a return type). This will reflect on how Spring JPA executes the query - it will call [`getSingleResult()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult--) on the [`javax.persistence.Query`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) interface, which will throw an `exception` if more than one objects satisfy the criteria.

> On what basis does `findBydepartmentId` return a single record?

On the basis that there's a single object with that Id, otherwise it will throw an exception.

> When or Why should i not use `findBy` in place of `findOneBy`?

Those two have different meanings and are not interchangeable.

`findOneBy` always results in [`getSingleResult()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult--) being invoked.

`findBy` has different behavior depending on the return type - as per the definitions given above.

Answer (score 9):

`findOneByXX` will ensure that there is only one or no value, if there are 2 values an exception will be thrown.

However `findByXX` doesn't make this check of uniqueness.

Comment: Optional<X> findBy returns IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException at least when using custom @Query

Comment: findByXX may throw this exception, depending on the declared result type. Entity T or Optional<T> will still result in invoking getSingleResult() which will throw IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException if more than 1 record matches the criteria.

Answer (score 7):

I have done some tests and Spring Data ignore all characters between the method (`find`, `delete`,...) and `By`.

In https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/14d5747f68737bb44441dc511cf16393d9d85dc8/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/PartTree.java#L65 it is the `\p{Lu}.*?` part.

Spring Data only use return type to decide how handle responses.

So it is possible to define these following methods even if it is not correct semantically.

```
Department findAllByDepartmentId(Long Id);
List<Department> findOneByDepartmentName(String name);
```