# How to return only an one instance in java?

Tags: java

I am coming to an issue where I am getting three objects instead of one object itself. (You can see my schema and the output result I am getting below). All I need to do is return a list of the Object Mapper that can transforms the collection in an array. In my controller this is the cause "public @ResponseBody List"  please help me to have it print like my schema. Thank you for the help..!

> Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class AutoCompleteController {

    private AutoCompleteService autoCompleteService;
    private EntityManager em;

    public AutoCompleteController(AutoCompleteService autoCompleteService, EntityManager em){
        this.autoCompleteService = autoCompleteService;
        this.em = em;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "jobs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<AutoComplete> getSalary(@RequestParam(value = "autocomplete") String autocompleteValue) {
      return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue);
    }

    public void getAllSalaries(HttpServletResponse res) {
        Stream<AutoComplete> stream = autoCompleteService.retrieveAllSalaries();
        DataStreamUtility.streamObjects(stream, res, em);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jobs")
    public @ResponseBody List < AutoComplete > getSalary(@RequestParam(value = "autocomplete", defaultValue = "1400") String autocompleteValue) {
        return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue);
     }

    public void getAllSalaries(HttpServletResponse res) {
      Stream < AutoComplete > stream = autoCompleteService.retrieveAllSalaries();
      DataStreamUtility.streamObjects(stream, res, em);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of list return single object

```
  public @ResponseBody AutoComplete getSalary();
```

Comment: I just did that. and on my return statement it says `incompatible types`

Comment: this line: `return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue);`

Comment: in AutoCompleteController you have to make change

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "jobs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody AutoComplete getSalary(@RequestParam(value = "autocomplete") String autocompleteValue) {
      return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue);
    }

Comment: can you please show me? I am having some trouble.  I removed `List<AutoComplete> getSalary` to `@ResponseBody AutoComplete getSalary();` and I am getting `incompatible types`. I believe my repo and services needs some change too?

Comment: public @ResponseBody AutoComplete getSalary(){
return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue).get(0);
} ?

Comment: hey @Oleksandr . your answer works it shows one object. But, when I want to get the search term of my data lets say `jobs?autocomplete=140` or anything possible term it wont get based on the searchTerm. It just returns only one object.

Comment: @Oleksandr and if you can see on my `rateType` it just only prints "annual". I want to print like my schema above. the other hourly and weekly rate types does not return.

Comment: @Samson Mkryan your questions sounds a little bit strange as for me. "All I need to do is return a list of the Object Mapper that can transforms the collection in an array." So could you please edit the question with mentioned restrictions. We have no any idea about the business logic you have and what you really want to get :)

Comment: as you can @Oleksandr. the schema shown above is what I want to get as my results. as of now it is with the provide code you gave me. It just prints one object (which is good) But, not the shows the expected way I want like my schema above. You get what I mean? :)

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your intention correctly, the problem here is that you're retrieving a list of entities where you only desired a single entity.

```
autocompleteRepository.findByJobClassCdStartsWith(jobClassCd);
```

In a nutshell: The "magic" findByXXX methods return either a list or a single entity; you should use findOneByXXXX instead to clarify.

Check this answer for further info, I think it's pretty well explained:
[Difference between findBy and findOneBy in Spring data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988295/difference-between-findby-and-findoneby-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: should I do like this `AutoComplete salaries = autocompleteRepository.findOneByJobClassCdStartsWith(jobClassCd);` ?

Comment: Replace the List<AutoComplete> by AutoComple in the repository, the service and the controller. And optionally, replace findByXXX by findOneByXXX .
(I've edit my response to avoid confusions)

Comment: now it stopped working. I get no data when I enter any term(s).

Comment: There is more than one AutoComplete row with the "jobClassCd" starting with the passed argument. Why did you expected to retrieve only one, then? Without knowing your data model, I cannot provider further help.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments you say `my rateType it just only prints "annual" ...  the other hourly and weekly rate types does not return`. By any chance have you created 3 objects with the same id but different rateTypes? It sounds to me like you need to make the rates an array each.

```
public String[] rateAnnual;
public String[] rateBiweekly;
public String[] Hourly;
```

Comment: inside my `Autocomplete` class where I initialize my objects of my column?

Comment: Yes I believe so. I'm not completely sure how you are creating the Autocomplete class originally, but the idea that 3 objects are being created seems likely to me

Comment: and then when I initialize those objects, what else I need to do? please advice. thanks

Comment: It's not easy to say because we can't see a complete picture. Based on the schema you had posted before I would think that you just fill out each of those arrays on a single object. You had some values for each rateType in your result previously, just put all three datasets into a single object that has the three arrays instead of 3 objects that had one array